# Selecting and modifying rows in a dataframe based on criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my first question, I only recently got into learning R so please be gentle.

X is a dataframe with variables V1 and V2.

```
set.seed(1)

V1 <- c(20:100)

V2 <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(81, 5)

X <- data.frame(V1, V2)
```

How do I:

a) Create a new dataframe with selection of rows at which variable V1 contains 5 at the position of the second digit? (meaning rows at which V1 has values 25, 35, 45, etc.)

b) Create a new dataframe with selection of rows from V2 at position at which V1 contains 5 at the position of the second digit? (meaning rows of V2 at which V1 has values 25, 35, 45, etc.)

It is essentially the same dataframe as the previous one but the procedure on constructing it is different.

c) Modify V2 by inserting a symbol(for the sake of question, say "X") between 3. an 4. symbol in V2?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Fran, welcome to SO. You could definitely improve your question by 1) setting a seed at the beginning of your code (to improve reproducibility), and 2) providing us with your expected output (i.e. how your dataframe (or multiple) should look like in the end).

Comment: @arg0naut91, thank you for feedback and adding the code snippets. The output would be to create a new df based on criteria from points a) and b) but I can manage that myself. Selecting the appropriate rows is the problem.

Comment: Thanks Fran, just FYI the function is `set.seed` with a dot. As for the output, at least knowing which exactly are the appropriate rows based on your input is helpful - as otherwise it can be hard to judge whether a solution produces the right output. I'm not saying you won't receive an answer, but it's more likely that way.

Comment: @arg0naut91, thanks, is this more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
temp <- X[substring(X$V1, 2, 2) == 5, ]
```

So answer to question a) is: `temp$V1`

and question b) is: `temp$V2`

For question c), we can use `substring` to paste 1st to 3rd letter of `V2`, insert "X" in between and the remaining string to create new column as `V3`.

```
temp$V3 <- paste0(substring(temp$V2, 1, 3), 'X', substring(temp$V2,  4))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses, you guys are great!

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `sub`

```
temp <- X[sub("^.(.).*", "\\1", X$V1) == 5, ]
```